# Parsing json data using php from youtube data api v3

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube data api v3 to retrieve data for search query using the below url
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=text&key=apikey&maxResults=25.

I am getting json response, while i am using json decode to parse the json data, i am getting empty result, can any one tell me how to retrieve the data

I am using below php code to parse

```
$videourl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=hello&key=apikey&maxResults=25";
            $json = file_get_contents($videourl);
            $data = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($data);
```

obtaining the json response from the below url:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=hello&key=apikey&maxResults=25

Comment: What is the value of the returned JSON from Google?

Comment: I am getting title,description,image details in json dictionary format

Comment: Please post the returned JSON and your PHP code.

Comment: check my modified question

Comment: what do you mean by empty result? what exactly is the output?

Comment: i am getting NUll as output, i need to parse the data from the given url using json and php
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=hai&key=AIzaSyDkLnMw5fYWY15IbEM8BftsnsOsxudgXO0&maxResults=25

Comment: Do a `var_dump($json); die;` straight after you do your `file_get_contents()` call, and make sure you're actually getting data back before you try and `json_decode()` it.

Comment: I try it, but getting NULL result

Comment: So we know your problem now isn't with `json_decode()`, but with `file_get_contents()`. So now, you should be googling "file_get_contents returns null" or "returns false".

Comment: file_get_contents returns false@Jimbo

Answer (score 0):

```
if (extension_loaded('curl')) {
    # create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    # set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://googleapis.com/.....");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    # Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    # grab URL and pass it to the browser
    if($json = curl_exec($ch)) {
        if(!($data = @json_decode($json)) instanceof stdClass) {
            trigger_error('Unable to decode json. '. print_r(error_get_last(), true));
        }
    }

    else trigger_error('CUrl Error:'.curl_error($ch));

    # close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

}

else trigger_error('CUrl unsupported', E_USER_WARNING);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should test the return value of file_get_contents. Be careful that this function will return FALSE in case of error (and not NULL). So you should test the return value with `=== FALSE` in order to not be confused by empty values.

In your case, if you are trying to access the exact url that you posted in your question, google is returning a code 400 (bad request), this is why you get a return of FALSE.

Comment: @Jimbo ummmm... look at his xp. he can't comment. this is the only way he can reply. blame stack exchange. instead everyone should comment but only high xp comments should be visible.

Comment: @mAsT3RpEE Ummm, look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).